# Referencing mscorlib in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

- My target framework is .NET Framework 4.
- The project is an MVC 3 project.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
- Windows 7 64bit

I'm trying to get an old project working on my fresh install of Windows 7 64 bit. When I try to compile the project I get the following error multiple times:

```
 Error  11  Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute..ctor'
```

I have read multiple questions on this same error but none of the solutions seems to work and are related to other target frameworks or different versions of MVC. Even more frustrating this exact same project compiles perfectly on my co-workers computer.

From what I understand, the reason I'm getting this error is because the project is looking for System.Runtime.CompilerServerices in System.Core but it was moved to mscorlib.

I am trying to re-ad mscorlib but when I try to add it as a compiled reference I get the following messages:

When I try to add mscorlib.dll 2.0:

```
 A reference to 'mscorlib.dll' could not be added. The ActiveX type library 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference. Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.
```

When I try to add mscorlib.dll 2.4:

```
 A reference to 'mscorlib.dll' could not be added. The ActiveX type library 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference. Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.
```

So when I try adding mscorlib v4.0.0.0 as a .NET reference I get the following error message:

```
 A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.
```

Am I missing a specific update? Do I need to re-reference mscorlib? If so how do I go about that? Is there a way to get the project to work with a System.Core.dll instead of mscorlib?

Comment: Have you installed VS 2010 SP1 and all updates?

Comment: Yes, all windows 7 updates and VS 2010 SP1 is installed.

Comment: I'm currently reapplying SP1 just to make sure that it was installed correctly.

Comment: There could be an issue of bad reference. Are you sure that your project/solution is pointing to correct version of the Framework?

Comment: @WarGravy - I Meant all VS 2010 updates, such as the Web Tools Update, and the Web Standards Update...

Comment: @StartingFromScratch We are both targeting .NET Framework v4.0. I also have v4.0.3 and v4.5.2 installed so it is possible those are interfering some how but my application target is v4.0

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I did not have the Web Standards update installed but I am still getting the same error after I just installed it.

Comment: @StartingFromScratch I'm looking at my .NET frameworks and it looks like I only have the 4 Multi-Targeting Pack and 4.5.2. I'm going to try to uninstall .NET and then install only v4.0

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So after uninstalling V4.5.2 and installing only V4.0 The project compiles, however when I try to debug I get this nasty error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help, I have uninstalled .Net 4.5 and installed 4.0 which allowed for the project to compile, however I received the following error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

To fix this, I then had to reinstall .Net 4.5 and reapply VS 2010 SP1. The project is now working!